# How can we change the position of legend using highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend, pie-chart

I am building a pie chart with highcharts js, but having a problem.

As shown below, I was able to put the legend on the bottom, but it's not aligned with the chart. I am trying to put the legend at the center of the chart, but it's somehow indented to the right. Here is the code I am using:

[image]

```
{
  chart: {
    animation: false,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
    events: {},
    plotShadow: false,
    style: {
      fontFamily: 'inherit',
      fontSize: '12px',
    },
    type: 'pie',
  },
  legend: {
    align: 'center',
    floating: false,
    enabled: true,
    labelFormat: '<span> {percentage:.2f}%</span>',
    layout: 'hoizontal',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    useHTML: true,
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Fleet by Truck Class',
    style: {
      fontSize: '24px',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
  },
  series: [{}],
  
}
```

Comment: I don't get the issue you're having. You may compare your full code with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ny928vk4/), or even better you could post a running version of your code (with all options and data) so we can see what the problem is. You misspelled  `layout: 'hoizontal'`, but that's OK because the layout in the picture is vertical and it doesn't have any other effect.